# PHPstorm, PHPdoc - можно ли задать описание переменной массива?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

Не знаю как точно выразиться. Есть массив-переменная, требуется автокомплит в phpstorm или type hinting или подсветка ключей массива.

К примеру если опишу переменную классом, то далее будут подсвечиваться все методы и свойства:

```
/**
 * @var \PDO
 */
```

Пытался искать и пробовать, но ничего не подошло, наводящие (если я неправильно выражаюсь) примеры в буржунете:

https://gist.github.com/mvriel/3822861
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713710/comment-associative-array-in-php-documentor
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414103/best-way-to-document-array-options-in-phpdoc

Возможно ли такое? **Пример массива**, который описать:

```
$array = [
    45 => [
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http:',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
        ],
        'curl_postfield' => 'id',
        'status_pattern' => '/[\da-z]{13}\s*(.+)/isu'
    ],
    46 => [
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'http:',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
        ],
        'curl_postfield' => 'post',
        'status_pattern' => '/[\da-z]{10}\s*(.+)/isu'
    ]
];
```

Comment: Если все элементы массива одинакового типа, то да - достаточно указать `@type \PDO[]`. Если элементы массива разного типа, то мне неизвестны способы задать соответствие ключ-тип, но сама такая конструкция является code smell, и от нее стоит избавиться.

Comment: @Etki обновил вопрос примером массива.

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас обычный массив из объектов одного типа, то это просто:

```
$array = [];
/** @var $array ExampleClass[] */

foreach ($array as $object) {
    // $object->getS... сработает автодополнение
    $object->getSomething();
}
```

Если у вас сложный массив, то без перехода к вложенным объектам не обойтись.

```
class ExampleClass
{
    /** @var ExampleEmbeddedClass[] */
    public $list = [];

    public function getSomething() {}
}

class ExampleEmbeddedClass
{
    public $property = 1;
}
```

В таком случае автодополнение замечательно работает:

[image: автодополнение]

Преобразование в массив проблемы не представляет, хоть и, в самом простом варианте, делается субоптимально через конвертацию в JSON и обратно:

```
$array = [
    42 => new ExampleClass(),
];
/** @var $array ExampleClass[] */
$array[42]->list[] = new ExampleEmbeddedClass();

$cleanArray = json_decode(json_encode($array), true);

var_export($cleanArray);
```

Получается такой простой массив:

```
array (
  42 => 
  array (
    'list' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'property' => 1,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Если вы точно знаете какие ключи у вас будут в массиве, то оптимальней может быть сделать конвертацию явно. Либо же вообще отказаться от этой идеи хотя бы в том что касается свойств cURL.

Comment: не понял ничего.

Comment: ассоциативные массивы не работают так - используйте объекты

Comment: если использовать объект вместо массива для описания конфига, авто дополнение кода будет работать? вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: да, будет работать